# New Laravel passport project setup clearly a basic problem

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Clearly I'm being silly somewhere, new laravel project outlined below, when I hit `/api/auth/logout` I get redirected back to `/` and I don't know why

`api.php`

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return response()->json([
       'Message' => 'TopBins API'
   ]);
})->name('handleNoMethod');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::post('register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    });
});
```

`auth.php`

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users'
    ],
],
```

`Authenticate.php`

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('handleNoMethod');
    }
}
```

Added to top of `$routeMiddleware`

`'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,`

Token generation by my register function:

```
$user = User::create($request->toArray());
    $token = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token', [])->accessToken;

    return response(json_encode([
        'access_token' => $token->token,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer'
    ]), 200);
```

Token given out is good and I use it as bearer in postman, this is something I do day to day, clearly something is odd with Laravel 8 which I haven't used before, or I'm going nuts

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are explicitly saying in `Authenticate.php` that when the user is not authenticated, a redirect to `route('handleNoMethod');` has to be done.

Also, if you expect an error response (401) instead of a redirect, you MUST send `Accept: application/json` in your postman request header.

Finally, your `logout` route is using the `auth:api` middleware, therefore you have to send the `Authorization: 'Bearer the_token'` in your request header since it's a protected route.

Answer (score -1):

You get redirected to `/` means you are not authenticated, You must send the token received from register method while requesting routes inside the AUTH middleware.

So when sending the `logout` request you must pass the following through headers:

```
{
    Authorization: 'Bearer {{token}}'
}
```

`token` represents the one received from register method

Comment: If you read my last line this is something I am doing in postman already